# CSS Check box image doesnt work

Tags: css

I had razor view in MVC with this code:

```
<td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m[i].checkExport)
</td>
```

I want to change the background of the check box so I wrote this code

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label {    
    background: url('images/delete.png') no-repeat;
    height:17px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {    
    background: url('images/delete.png') no-repeat;
    height:17px;
}
```

but it shows nothing when I run it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: We need to see the actual output HTML involved.Where is the label in your scenario?

Comment: I used razor view, its seem different from pure html, so i dont know where it puts the label in? Do i need to create label for this?

Comment: You're trying to select a label with your CSS so I'd say it's essential. Regardless, your must have actual HTML on the final page and that's what we need to see.

Comment: <td>
               <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The checkExport field is required." name="[0].checkExport" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="[0].checkExport" type="hidden" value="false">
            </td> here is the original code of html

Comment: According to that code your selector wouldn't work. `input[type="checkbox"]+label` would apply to labels directly following a checkbox in the markup. Your checkbox is followed by a hidden input, and no label at all. It would have to look like this: `<input type="checkbox"><label>Labeltext</label>` for the selector to work.

Comment: There is no `label` rendered in your output. You need `@Html.LabelFor(m=>m[i].checkExport)` as well

Comment: @Html.LabelFor(m=>m[i].checkExport) I add this code, but it only show text, do not show the image

Comment: <label for="">checkExport</label> here is the html when i use @Html.LabelFor(m=>m[i].checkExport)

Answer (score 4):

Your CSS implies the existence of a `label` **immediately after** the `input` in question.

If the `label` does not exist, nothing will show as you have told the `input` to not display.

The usual structure would be as follows:

```
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" />
<label for="chk"></label>
```

NOTE: The `input` and associated `label` are linked by the id/for connection. This is essential to ensure that clicking on the `label` activates the associated `input`.

Then your CSS woudl apply accordingly.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]+label {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/16/Delete-icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    background-image: url(http://www.fatcow.com/images/icons/tick.png);
}
```

Demo below :

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/16/Delete-icon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  background-image: url(http://www.fatcow.com/images/icons/tick.png);
}
```

```html
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" />
<label for="chk"></label>

<input id="chk2" type="checkbox" />
<label for="chk2"></label>
```

Comment: I used html helper, which code in html helper will match with <label for="chk"></label>.